# RefTeX won't find my .bib file in local library tree

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex, biber, reftex

RefTeX gives out the following error when trying to insert a citation:

> ```
>   No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available
> ```

I keep a master `.bib` file in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/master_bib.bib`. Biblatex-biber recognize the file when I run it, so a bibliography is generated. The problem is that RefTeX does not recognize the file and yields the above error. I have also placed the `.bib` file in the same directory as the `.tex` file, with the same results.

This post seemed promising https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23780/reftex-wont-detect-my-bib-file but that one self-resolved automagically.

The [RefTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.pdf) (p.20) says that

> If you do not use BibTEX, but the document contains an explicit
>   `thebibliography` environment, RefTEX will collect its information from
>   there.

however, I don't see where or how I could include this.

How can I get this to work?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=authoryear, 
    maxcitenames=2, 
    sorting=nyt,
    backref=true
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{master_bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    Some text. \parencite{Mays:2005, Chow:1998}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

I'm running Emacs 24, with AUCTeX 11.86, TeX Live 2011 from MacTeX.

Comment: Have you tried using `\bibliography` instead of `\addbibresource`? I suspect that RefTeX is looking for that (or maybe `\bibliographystyle`) to work, so it may be worth a try.

Comment: Does putting the following in your .emacs help? `(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/master_bib.bib"))`

Comment: @JosephWright, I tried `\bibliography` but RefTeX still does not find the `.bib` file. Wouldn't `\bibliographystyle` be BibTex syntax?

Comment: @N.N., adding the default bibliography to my .emacs did not help either.

Comment: Something did help, but I can't reproduce it. There seems to be an auxiliary file (not sure which one) that when present, allows RefTeX to work. Mucking around, I got it to recognize a `samplebib.bib` in the same directory; however, it wouldn't redirect to the `master_bib.bib` in the local Library, and even when the `samplebib` was renamed, it still referred to the old references it had. I'll try to replicate it and check back in with results.

Comment: @N.N., I take it back: I had a typo and that's why it didn't work. Would you post it as an answer so I can mark it? Without that line, RefTeX would only recognize `.bib` files in the same directory as the `.tex` file. Also, once it failed to work once, it would keep failing to work unless I restarted Emacs. Reopening the buffer after setting the correct `.bib` file did not change that it didn't work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are two ways to make RefTeX find your bibliography. I suggest to use *both* approaches for robustness.

- To make RefTeX recognize your bibliography you can add it to the list `reftex-default-bibliography`. To do this add the following to your .emacs:

  ```lisp
  ;; So that RefTeX finds my bibliography
  (setq reftex-default-bibliography '("path/to/bibfile.bib"))
  ```

  and replace `path/to/bibfile.bib` with the path to your bib file. Note that it is a list so that it can contain several paths if you want to point it to several bibliographies. This approach is good for accessing your .bib file via RefTeX in Org-mode.
- Another way to make RefTeX recognize the bibliography in `\addbibresource` you can add it to the variable `reftex-bibliography-commands` by adding the following to your .emacs:

  ```lisp
  ;; So that RefTeX also recognizes \addbibresource. Note that you
  ;; can't use $HOME in path for \addbibresource but that "~"
  ;; works.
  (setq reftex-bibliography-commands '("bibliography" "nobibliography" "addbibresource"))
  ```

Both variables [are documented in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/reftex_60.html).

Comment: A related issue is that biber looks for your .bib using kpsewhich too so it will find it if it's in your tex tree somewhere. RefTeX can also do this but you have to configure it. It's in the RefTeX manual somewhere.

Comment: @N.N. w.r.t. the first alternative you offered: Given that different documents have different `.bib` files, are you suggesting to add for each such instance an entry in the global scale (i.e. the `.emacs` setting)? The second suggestion solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Dror Indeed, `reftex-default-bibliography` is a list so it can take several paths to bib files. If you have a bib file you only use for one or few documents I am guessing you could set it with a [file variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) instead of adding it to the variable in your .emacs.

Comment: @N.N. Since setting `reftex-bibliography-commands` solved the issue, I don't see a reason to use the file variables. Please correct me in case I'm missing something.

Comment: @Dror `reftex-default-bibliography` are good for those cases where you have not yet added a `addbibresources` or similar to your document and also for when using RefTeX in Org-mode.

Comment: "Note that it is a list so that it can contain several paths if you want to point it to several bibliographies. This approach is good for accessing your .bib file via RefTeX in Org-mode." @N.N. Does this actually work for you? I've had no luck using multiple default bibliographies. There seems to be a bug in RefTex which has not been fixed: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2013-05/msg00005.html

Comment: Are these methods still expected to work? I'm using reftex 24.4 (emacs 24.5) on Kubuntu 16.04. The first methods works for me, but the second (which is more flexible) does not. I also tried `(setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables '("~/text/include/"))` which also had no effect.

Answer (score 18):

Adding

```
%%% reftex-default-bibliography: ("path/to/bibfile.bib")
```

at the end of my file with other commands related to the file looks better to me.

Comment: A local variable at the end of every file is another possible way to go about it. However, the question referred to a master bibliography that could be used by any file, new and existing. Going the local-variable way would force me to add that line on every new file, whereas modifying the .emacs would give me a permanent solution with just one input.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by inserting `'(reftex-use-external-file-finders t)` into my emacs init file.

It makes RefTeX use the appropriate command from `reftex-external-file-finders` to find the file. In my case that is `kpsewhich -format=.bib %f`. 
[The default is](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Finding-Files.html) looking in the folders specified in the environment variables `BIBINPUT` and `TEXINPUT`.

I prefer this variant mainly because I expect that emacs and latex will use the same method for determining what bib file to use. It also feels more flexible, as you do not need to modify it if you create another central biblography.

Comment: What does this answer add to the one provided by m42?

Comment: The value in that m42 change does not have an effect if you do not change set `reftex-use-external-file-finders` to true. In addition m42's entries are already included in the variable and are therefore redundant(I expect this to hold for later auctex versions).

Answer (score 4):

I've seen people suggest that there's a fault in RefTeX, corrected by inserting

```lisp
(setq reftex-external-file-finders
'(("tex" . "/path/to/kpsewhich -format=.tex %f")
  ("bib" . "/path/to/kpsewhich -format=.bib %f")))
```

This is not necessary for me.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the issue may just be that the file has not been parsed. This has happened to me a few times eventhough it should've been parsed when opened (especially when I have multiple latex projects open at the same time).

In such situations (supposing your `reftex-bibliography-commands` contains `addbibresource` already), the quickest fix is just `M-x reftex-parse-all`.