# How to properly make reftex work with multiple biblatex bibs?

Tags: biblatex, emacs, reftex

I saw a comment in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141180/9162) that support for multiple *addbibresource* has been integrated into Emacs. However I'm using a few custom *sty*s from where I require *biblatex* package with all the necessary parameters.

For some reason in spite of *TeX-parse-self* set to non-nil, I'm still getting nil for `(reftex-using-biblatex-p)`. I really don't want to move requirement for biblatex out of sty file such that "poor-man's check" for `\usepackage` would work in *reftex-using-biblatex-p*. I'd consider it as a last resort.

Is there a workaround to add *biblatex* into *TeX-active-styles*? Did I miss something?

**Update**

Here is an example. Run it once, then open in Emacs, comment out *common.sty* producing block (select and hit <kbd>M-;</kbd>), revisit the file (<kbd>C-x C-v</kbd>), and, finally, try <kbd>C-c [</kbd> to add *b2016*. It won't find it, but will find *a2015*.

```
% runme with latexmk -pdf thisfile.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{common.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{common}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,
backref=true,
sorting=nyvt,
url=false,
isbn=false,
doi=true,
eprint=false,
firstinits=true,
mincitenames=3,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test1.bib}
@article{a2015,
    title = {Test 1},
    volume = {66},
    pages = {423--430},
    number = {6},
    journaltitle = {Some journal},
    author = {Author, B.C.},
    date = {2015-03-03},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test2.bib}
@article{b2016,
    title = {Test 2},
    volume = {33},
    pages = {123--234},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Another journal},
    author = {Creator, D.E.},
    date = {2016-03-03},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{common}
\addbibresource{test1.bib}
\addbibresource{test2.bib}

\begin{document}

hello\parencite{b2016}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Update 2**

The above scenario was tested on [64 bit Emacs](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/) 25.0.50.1 and AUCTeX 11.88 on MS Windows. Original value for `reftex-bibliography-commands` already [contains *addbibresource*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54739/9162).

**Update 3**

Save the following into `startup.el` and use `emacs -q --load startup.el`.

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
(setq reftex-save-parse-info t) ; I didn't know I had it either in my config
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'reftex-mode)
```

Apparenty AUCTeX is not involved at all. Also it looks like only real `\usepackage{biblatex}` results in both *bib*s in *rel* file, i.e. filecontents trick with a dummy file won't work. I wonder if AUCTeX affected *TeX-active-styles* and now only "poor-man's check" work in `(reftex-using-biblatex-p)`.

If you have no `\usepackage{biblatex}` and no rel file, the latter will be created with only first bib. Once you add `\usepackage{biblatex}`, it won't affect rel unless you delete it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as with this example, I do get *biblatex* in *TeX-active-styles*, but things still do not show up in reftex browser.

Comment: I can confirm RefTeX has some problems, but I think the example should be simplified: load `biblatex` with a simple `\usepackage`, don't write a new style file to an external file.  I suggest you to report the bug with `M-x reftex-report-bug <RET>`.

Comment: I stand corrected: I tested again properly, your example works for me (provided that you create the parsed files for the files generated filecontents)

Comment: @giordano After running latexmk, delete *filecontents* blocks, close Emacs, delete all files but *filecontents* generated ones, make sure to delete *thisfile.rel* or whatever it was named. I'm 100% positive I can reproduce both bugs individually with emacs-bin-w64-20150217-16d91bc.7z

Comment: `thisfile.rel`? Who should generate this file? I followed again your recipe and I cannot reproduce your bug (Emacs 24.4 and AUCTeX 11.88). The relevant configuration you have for RefTeX could help.

Comment: *rel* file is a `;; RefTeX parse info file` according to its first line. I suspect it usually shows up upon quitting Emacs if `(reftex-using-biblatex-p)` was returning non-nil, and, probably, if `TeX-auto-save` was set.

Comment: I see. I've never set `reftex-save-parse-info` to `t` (actually I didn't even know that variable until a few minutes ago).  I repeat the suggestion to post also your RefTeX and AUCTeX configuration, so I (or anybody else) can test with your exact setup.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce even with your setup: when I open `thisfile.tex`, RefTeX is able to use both bibliography databases.  One only caveat, I already said many times, is that you have to parse the `common.sty` file with `C-c C-n` in order to generate the style file.  Ah, the LaTeX mode hook for AUCTeX is `LaTeX-mode-hook`, not `latex-mode-hook`, I fixed it in your post.

Comment: Or did you mean to use Emacs default `tex-mode` instead of AUCTeX?

Comment: It is reproducible for me with and without AUCTeX every time. The latter only makes it possible to use *TeX-active-styles* shortcut in `(reftex-using-biblatex-p)`. Does your `thisfile.rel` has both files in *bib* entry? Have you tried deleting entire file and using `startup.el` I posted? <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> make no difference to me either on the line with `common.sty` inclusion or after *ffap*ing in there. Is it supposed to call *(TeX-normal-mode)*?

Comment: Yes, my `thisfile.rel` has this entry: `(bib "/tmp/test1.bib" "/tmp/test2.bib")`; yes, I did try with your startup file; and yes, `C-c C-n` in AUCTeX runs `(TeX-normal-mode)` (try `C-h k C-c C-n` to see the the command bound to that shortcut)

Answer (score 5):

I'll dare to answer my own question at least regarding workaround for those who need it right here and right now. It drove me nuts that same example worked in one folder and did not in another. And apparently revisiting file doesn't make much difference, so for a clean try, I'd suggest closing Emacs completely.

There are **2 bugs** I suspect. One is that **reftex fails to recognize biblatex usage when included indirectly**. And another one is that **reftex fails to properly update *rel* file** (`thisfile.rel` if you named your original file as `thisfile.tex`) file regardless where `\usepackage{biblatex}` is.

There are 2 ways around it. Add that bib file manually into `thisfile.rel`. Make sure you quit Emacs before doing all that stuff. Due to the bug, it will stay as you edited *bib* entry there.

Another way is to delete `thisfile.rel` if it exists, and add `\usepackage{biblatex}` temporarily so `rel` file will be recreated on save (provided you enabled `TeX-auto-save`, but who didn't?). After doing so you'll get `./auto/thisfile.el` generated by AUCTeX (?) with biblatex mentioned in it so reftex knows that and can create `thisfile.rel`. You could also have used *filecontents* with some dummy file. Once you got all entries in your `rel` file, you can ditch `\usepackage{biblatex}` from the main document if you include it somewhere from your styles. After doing this, there will be no *biblatex* in `./auto/thisfile.el`, but *bib* entry in `thisfile.rel` won't be recreated either.

**Update:**
The above text was edited to use explicit names rather than `\jobname` in general sense to avoid confusion. Also it is clarified what is going on in the second workaround regarding `./auto/thisfile.el` and *biblatex* entry.

Comment: It's true AUCTeX cannot handle properly `\jobname`, but in your example there is no `\jobname`, so I cannot understand that point.  Instead, it's false AUCTeX cannot recognize `\usepackage{biblatex}` written in another file, the problem could be there is no auto file associated to it, you have to visit that file and issue `C-C- C-n`.

Comment: I should have made it clear about `\jobname`, I used it as a placeholder since I didn't name example file explicitly aside from *thisfile.tex*, so it would be *thisfile.rel*, etc.