# Reftex and AMSRefs

Tags: emacs, reftex, amsrefs

I have been using Emacs Reftex for labelling and referencing. However, I could not use it with AMSRefs. I tried using Reftex with its standard setup both the ways (i) including the bib entries in the tex document (ii) importing the bib entries from a ``Citations.lbt'' file. However, it would give me a message " No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available".

Then I manually added the path to my ``Citations.lbt'' file in the .emacs file. This removed the above message. But when I type key for a citation and ask to autocomplete (with tab), Reftex tells me that there is no completion available for this entry. The same message appears even if the full entry is typed and entered. This happens when the citations and included in both the fashions mentioned earlier.

I also added the command "bibselect" in the .emacs file and the same thing happens; indeed, in this case, I import the citations from Citations.ltb file.

The following discussion would tell you how I added the path and commands in the .emacs file: [RefTeX won't find my .bib file in local library tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54739/reftex-wont-find-my-bib-file-in-local-library-tree) .
The manual also describe this.

Now I found that the Reftex manual and all the discussions involve bibtex and not AMSRefs. The following, and kind of old thread, asks the question if Reftex works with AMSRefs: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2007-06/msg00005.html .

For some reasons, I have to stick to AMSRefs. My questions are: if AMSRef works in Reftex? If it does could someone help me with how to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid the state hasn't changed since 2007.  Alas, the answer is RefTeX doesn't support AMSRefs.

Comment: @ArashEsbati -- please add that as an answer, so this question won't end up on the unanswered list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

I have just written a package that adds amsrefs support to reftex.  It works for me but I would be grateful to have some more testers.

Find it here: https://github.com/franburstall/amsreftex

Comment: When I try to install your `amsrefs` package as per instruction via MELPA, I get the error `(error "Package ‘amsreftex’ is unavailable")`

Comment: Maybe do `M-x package-refresh-contents` and try again?

Comment: Doesn't help.  Is there an actual MELPA repository I can go to and look if it's there?

Comment: Sure: https://melpa.org/#/amsreftex

Comment: OK, thanks, so after some struggle, `amsreftex` did show up in the package list and I could install it.  I now have the impression  that it is designed to handle `amsrefs` databases and not to insert various versions of the `\cite` command (such as `\citelist`) into the `latex` source file and fetch entries from a `.bib` file.  In the `Ref` menu's `Citation style` submenu, I can check the box next to `Amsrefs`, but that interface seems to be outdated since it doesn't bring up `\citelist`.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: You are correct: the main point of `amsreftex` is to handle `.ltb`databases.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the situation has not changed since 2007.  Alas, RefTeX does not support amsrefs.

Comment: It's still the case.  Quite a few journals require the use of `amsrefs` (besides AMS journals, like Indiana U. J. of Math), so we have no choice but use it.  Since it can be used with `bibtex`, perhaps `reftex` could just support the citation commands, so not yet the database format.  The citation formats of `amsrefs` actually are really useful, and they solve some problems with the `\cite[][]{}` formats.

Comment: @MátéWierdl - The biggest issue is that I don't use `amsrefs` (more precisely, LaTeX at all) and have no clue about `amsrefs`.  Do you want to provide a patch against AUCTeX and write a `amsrefs.el`?  It should be easy to _borrow_ some ideas from `biblatex.el` and/or `natbib.el`.  Otherwise you can try the `amsreftex` by @FranBurstall.  Installing it form MELPA is this simple form in you init file away: `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)` and then `M-x list-packages RET` and then search for `amsreftex`.

Comment: Thanks @ArashEsbati, I could get the `amsreftex` package for `Emacs`, but it doesn's do what I thought it would do, as I explain in my comment after the first answer.